# Reading # of vowels from String in java

Tags: java, string

there. I need some assistance. I'm working on having the user input text, reverse the text, then read the number of vowels in the text and tell them how many vowels were in the reversed text.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 System.out.println ("Please type in whatever you want ");
 Scanner type_input = new Scanner (System.in);
 Scanner type_input = new Scanner (System.in);
 StringBuilder type_output = new StringBuilder();
 type_output.append(type_hold);
 type_output=type_output.reverse();
 System.out.println("Is this what you types in? " + type_output);   

 for(int vowel_num = 0; vowel_num< type_hold.length(); vowel_num++)
    {
        if((type_hold.charAt(vowel_num) =='a')||(type_hold.charAt(vowel_num) =='e')||
            (type_hold.charAt(vowel_num) =='o')||(type_hold.charAt(vowel_num) =='i')||
            (type_hold.charAt(vowel_num) =='u')){    

        System.out.println("There are " + vowel_num + " vowels in " + type_hold);
    }
```

But when I get it to typing in to running it i get the following. I'm not sure where I'm messing up.

```
run:
Please type in whatever you want 
hello
Is this what you types in? olleh
There are 1 vowels in hello
There are 4 vowels in hello
```

Edit: I figured it out. Thank you to everyone for the help!

Comment: I'm betting that the number of vowels in the reversed text is the same as the number of vowels in the original text...

Comment: @ajb I had a good laugh at that comment. However I think he's just got 2 practice tasks here -- reverse text and count vowels. I don't think he was trying to count them in the original *and* reversed text.

Comment: Why do you have the `type_input =` line twice? The other problem is taht `vowel_num` is not counting the number of values but rather giving the position of them.

Comment: You're not actually counting the vowels.  To do this, you need a counter variable that starts at 0, and you need to add 1 to it whenever you see a vowel.  I'll let you try to work out the details yourself.

Comment: Stephen, your code-snippet is a mess, won't even compile. Please learn [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Hack-R I made a few mistakes when copying the code from my netbeans into here. I'm trying to self teach myself, and I'm just picking a few simple projects and going from there.

Comment: @Ajb thank you, looking at the example below let me realize that and i clearly see where i was messing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What is `type_hold`? Didn't see you instantiate it, and you are using it.
2. What `vowel_num`? The index you are looping through the string? or the number of vowels you have counted?

What you should have done to count vowels in a string:

Assuming `index` is the index of the string we are currently scanning, `vowel_count` is the count of vowels you have encountered.

```
int vowel_count = 0;
for(int index = 0; index < type_hold.length(); index++) {
    if((type_hold.charAt(index) =='a') || 
       (type_hold.charAt(index) =='e') || 
       (type_hold.charAt(index) =='o') || 
       (type_hold.charAt(index) =='i') || 
       (type_hold.charAt(index) =='u')){

         // character at vowel_index is a vowel.
         // you have encountered 1 more vowel! 
         System.out.println("Character at " + index + " is a vowel.");
         vowel_count ++;
     }
}

System.out.println("There are " + vowel_count + " vowels in " + type_hold);
```

Comment: I would also suggest to rename `vowel_index ` to `inputIndex` or something like that, because that's what it is.

Comment: Thank you. looking at your example i realize where i was messing up. type _hold was an early variable meant to hold input from the scanner variable new_input so i could use it in my StringBuilder variable type_output. I'm sure there was a better way I could do it, but I don't know how yet. So vowel_index would would add a value to the integer for each instance of a vowel it saw, then for loop would add a value to vowel_num based oin that?

Comment: sorry to confuse you, when i say vowel_index is index, i mean it is an index for you to iterate through the string, so, in each for loop, it is incremented to look at the next character in the string.

Comment: @LihauTan That's why I suggested to rename it.

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer renamed.

Answer (score 3):

Java 8 streams can be used on the character array inside the String.

```
StringBuilder type_hold = new StringBuilder();
long vowel_num = type_hold.toString().toLowerCase().chars()
        .filter(it -> "aeiou".indexOf(it) != -1).count();
```

Comment: I assume, Stephen's a beginner in programming, just learning the basics. IMHO Streams and Lambdas are not for beginners.

Comment: I would use `it -> "aeiou".indexOf(it) >= 0` ;) +1

Answer (score -1):

Modified your code a bit; take a look;

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  System.out.println ("Please type in whatever you want ");
  Scanner type_input = new Scanner (System.in);
  Scanner type_input = new Scanner (System.in);
  StringBuilder type_output = new StringBuilder();
  type_output.append(type_hold);
  type_output=type_output.reverse();
  System.out.println("Is this what you types in? " + type_output);   

  int count=0;
  for(int vowel_num = 0; vowel_num< type_hold.length(); vowel_num++)
  {
    if((type_hold.charAt(vowel_num) =='a') ||(type_hold.charAt(vowel_num) =='e')||
        (type_hold.charAt(vowel_num) =='o')||(type_hold.charAt(vowel_num) =='i')||
        (type_hold.charAt(vowel_num) =='u')){    

    //System.out.println("There are " + vowel_num + " vowels in " + type_hold);                      Instead of this

    count++;
   }

System.out.println("There are " + count + " vowels in " + type_hold);
}
```

This should done your work.

Comment: 1. Doesn't even compile.  // 2. You shouldn't only "fix" the code, you should also explain what's wrong in the first place.